HTML unstructured and structured list - Unable to change the connecting line color between last element and element before last in HTML
I am using HTML to represent status of request in graphical format and sending this via email - HTML is called via Python code. HTML output is similar to the image - I faced the challenge of last message got truncated. So introduced some 'dummy' - so that one element will be added at the last and data truncation can be avoided - it worked and I made the last element invisible by giving background color as white.

But unable to make the connecting line to the last element color to white. I have used almost all the options of

li.active::before,
ul.active::before,
nth-last-child,
nth-last-type,
last-child.

But it is not working. Please help.


ul {
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul:before,
.active:after {
  content: ' ';
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #34ae25;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  margin-top: 18px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.active:after {
  border-color: #b7b7b7;
}

ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1b6c05;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

` li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.marker-number {
  font-size: 14px;
}

li.active {
  background: #ffcb0f;
}

.active~li {
  background: #b7b7b7;
}

li.emp {
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

ul:after,
.emp:before {
  border: #FFFFFF;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

~li.emp {
  border: #FFFFFF;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

li:nth-last-child(2)::after {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul.lastchild.previousElementSibling {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
}

li.completed {
  background: #228B22;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0em;
}

li:last-child::before {
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
}




Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research .  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor. In this case please update the snippet I made with relevant RENDERED HTML and relevant frameworks
